# ListView in Fragment won't refresh

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a list in a fragment, which is able to grow when pressing a button.

The list is inside a fragment.

Here's a part of my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static String[] values = {
        ""
    };
    private static ListView listView;

    public static NotesDbAdapter helper;
    public static ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static CustomPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    public static CustomListAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this);
        helper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        helper.open();
        pagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new ListFragment());
        Log.d("DEBUG", "HELPER COUNT: " + Integer.toString(helper.fetchAllNotes().getCount()));
        values = new String[helper.fetchAllNotes().getCount()];
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = "KLAPPT";
        }
        updateList();
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

    public void addNote() {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "new note");
        helper.createNote("", "");
        updateList();
    }


    public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private Context context;
        private int res;
        private TextView textView;
        public CustomListAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.res = R.layout.list_item;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false);
            textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_textview);
            textView.setText(values[position]);
            return rowView;
        }


    }

    public static class ListFragment extends Fragment {


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
            listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_listview);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public void updateList() {
        values = new String[helper.fetchAllNotes().getCount()];
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = "KLAPPT";
        }
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

So now I would like to add an Item to the list by pressing on an actionbar item. That works, I can confirm that. But to see a change I have to leave the app and re-enter to see any changes or change screen orientation to landscape and back.
I want it to immeadiately show the updated list, but I don't know how.

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

does **NOT** work for me, I don't know why. 
I also tried to create a new listAdapter like so:

```
listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

and set the listView to that adapter:

```
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

But all I get is a force close (I don't know why).

So know I haven't got any idea how to fix that problem.
I would like to be able to refresh the listView immediately when calling the `updateList()` method.

I get this logCat when trying to apply a new adapter to the listview:

```
 06-19 18:17:32.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12259): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ochs.androidnotepad/com.ochs.androidnotepad.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: change getApplicationContext()  to MainActivity.this and post logcat

Comment: @IllegalArgument I added my logcat output when trying to apply a new adapter to the listview

Comment: are you able to see the list first time??

Comment: Yes, I currently got about 10 items in the list, but sometimes it only shows 1 up when starting the app from eclipse. After that I can quit the app and re-enter it and it shows all elements of the list

Comment: Why `ListFragment ` is static, please remove it and check